# Check if input string conforms with DB collation

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, collation

What we have is a table with an email field - collation `latin1_swedish_ci` because of the limitations of our email service.

[image: Full table description]

This table is checked when a new user arrives to see if he was already subscribed.

Comes along a user with characters in their email that would not be valid for this particular collation. Take for instance `hsıasdf@test.com`

[image]

---

> Would it be possible to determine before saving if a string will
>   adhere to the collation rules of database?
>
> Is it possible for me to check before any DB trigger to
>   save/create/find; if an entry with this particular email will
>   agree with the collation? Some regex maybe?

Comment: Rails default collection is set to `utf8_general_ci`. Do you want to change the entire rails application to use `latin_swedish_ci`.

Comment: @Coderhs the entire application already uses `latin_swedish_ci`. I just dont want to run a db query if the input value is not going to be supported

Comment: Is said email system sharing the database with your rails application? Condemning your whole application to `latin_swedish_ci` seems like a pretty harsh solution.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a valid method to use exactly this query as a testfunction by executing it and return false when mysql throws an error?

Comment: @Solarflare it could, but this issue is not limited to this table alone. There are multiple places where the collation mismatch would raise an error. I could wrap all those snippets in rescue blocks but if there were a more elegant way to do this..

Comment: No, I meant: If you have a string that you want to test, use a global function that will (for all strings that you want to test to be swedish) just execute this query against this table. If it's ok, it should be fine for every other table with swedish collation. The other way I would see is to check the sources/mapping files to get the allowed characters and use this to create a charactertest.

Comment: @max The whole application already uses latin swedish. And migrating the entire dB is hence not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby you can use [`String#encode`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-encode) to test converting strings between common encodings.

However this won't help as you want to test a MySQL specific collation.

What you can do is use a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html):

```
User.transaction do
  if User.create!(email: 'hsıasdf@test.com')
    puts "yup its valid"
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

However it is not terribly effective. If you wanted it to run before saving you could use a custom validation.

If possible I would use the MySQL standard `utf` and `utf8_general_ci` and convert only at the application boundary where it needs to interact with the email system. Using a non UTF-8 encoding will give you plenty of headaches and may be very detrimental in the long run if the bad email system is changed for example.

You can select collate on the fly with:

```
SELECT users.email COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci AS users.collated_email
FROM users
```

Comment: Using Ruby 1.8.7 - so no use of encode. Changing collation would be a problem as latin is currently our default collation. Modifying the entire db is something I would avoid.

Comment: You need to upgrade your Ruby ASAP. 1.8.7 was retired back in 2013 and has many security vulnerabilities and is much slower than 2.x.

Comment: Yes I am aware. Infact a Ruby and Rails upgrade is something we are prepping for and will be done in a few weeks. This issue will still have to be dealt with separately.

Comment: I would check first if the error is not due to ActiveRecord using the wrong collation - try `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.collation` and `mysql> show variables like 'collation%';`. And then try using transactions.

Answer (score 0):

```
RoR: application_controller.rb

  def configure_charsets
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    suppress(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET NAMES UTF8'
    end   end
```

You should go with utf8 (or utf8mb4), not the very limited latin1 (which handles only Western Europe).

```
ALTER TABLE user_subscriptions
    CONVERT TO utf8;
```

(ditto for any other tables).

Your title talks about checking.  But I think that when you get everything using the same `CHARACTER SET`, there won't need to be any 'checking'.

Answer (score 0):

Try with bellow query.It may help to you.

```
select * from user_subscription where email=cast('hsıasdf@test.com' as char CHARSET latin1);
```